# mongoose how to project protected fields on update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following model in mongoose. `projects` field is `protected`.

```
var UserProjectSchema = new Schema({
    user : ObjectId
    , projects : {type : [ObjectId], select:false} //protected field
    , projectCount : Number
});
```

I want that `protected` field after update so that I could return the new set of `projects`.

```
UserProjectSchema.statics.addProject = function(userId, projectId) {

    UserProject.findOneAndUpdate({
       user:userId
    },
    {
       $addToSet: {"projects" : projectId}
     , $inc : {"projectCount" : 1}
    },

    {
     upsert : true
     //project : '+projects' it won't work
    },

    function(err, doc){
     //doc.projects is undefined

     // UserProject.findOne({user:userId},'+projects', function(err, doc){
     //    doc.projects is now available but this extra query ???
     //})
    });
}

var UserProject = mongoose.model('user_projects', UserProjectSchema);
```

Mongoose returns the updated document after successful query but lacks to specify the fields to project.
Is there any way to specify what fields to project after updating in mongoose so that I could remove the extra query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a [select](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) parameter in your `options` param and list all the fields you would like to project.

```
{
  upsert : true,
  select:{"projects":1} // all the fields you would want to select
}
```

Comment: Welcome. It happens. ;-)